# C# button image to large when application is running

Tags: c#, .net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpSlt.jpg)

I try to use backgroundimage and image and dock them to the left and text to the right but it doesn't work.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can set the BackgroundImageLayout-Property (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimagelayout?view=net-5.0) to e.g. Stretch or what fits best.